# MDX Rank request returning unexpected results

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, pentaho

I wrote this fairly simple MDX request to get the **rank by sales count of each gender**:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[rank] AS RANK(
      [Gender].CurrentMember,
      Order(
         [Gender].Members,
         [Measures].[salescount],
         BDESC
      ),
      [Measures].[salescount]
   )
SELECT [Gender].Members ON COLUMNS,
[Measures].[rank] ON ROWS
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
```

The **problem** is that the result is wrong, I know M has more sales than F:

```
Axis #0:
  {}
Axis #1:
  {[Measures].[rank]}
Axis #2:
  {[Gender].[All Genders]}
  {[Gender].[F]}
  {[Gender].[M]}
Row #0: 1
Row #1: 2
Row #2: 3
```

If I use "Country" instead of "Gender", same problem: the *rank* is given according to the **alphabetical order**, instead of based on the sales count. *(ie: all countries come listed in alphabetical order, with rank 1,2,3,4,...)*

How can I fix the request to correctly show each gender's salescount rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[rank] AS RANK(
      [Reseller].CurrentMember,
      Order(
         [Reseller].Members,
         [Measures].[salescount],
         BDESC
      ),
      [Measures].[salescount]
   )
SELECT Order(
         [Reseller].Members,
         [Measures].[salescount],
         BDESC
      ).Item([theShopWhoseRankIWant]) ON COLUMNS,
[Measures].[rank] ON ROWS
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
```

Sorry for the noise, I hope this might help someone :-)